# How to divide a vector on a sphere into northern and southern components?

Tags: vectors, physics, vector-analysis, spheres

Suppose we have $S^2$ and a vector $\vec{A}$ pointing at a random direction. Let us divide the sphere into $S_N$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $S_S$ for $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \pi$. Then how can I show the following?
$$ A_N \backsim \frac{1-\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \hat{e}_{\phi} $$
$$ A_S \backsim \frac{1+\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \hat{e}_{\phi} $$

How do I split an arbitrary radial vector as above to a north and southern part therefore? Note that $\phi$ is the other angle with $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi.$

The question arise from page 10 of [this document](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9603086v2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a misunderstanding. The text is not dividing a vector $\vec A$ into two components. It is describing how to consistently define a vector potential for the magnetic field of a magnetic monopole despite the fact that no single vector potential can describe this field. It does so by defining two different vector potentials on the two hemispheres and showing that they are compatible at the boundary. There is no vector $\vec A$ of which $\vec A_N$ and $\vec A_S$ form components.

Comment: I see, of course this makes sense. But why is the definition of $A_N$ and $A_S$ the way it is. I.e. the particular form involving cosines and sines must arise in a specific way, right?

Comment: @Marion: They don't say how they came up with this form; there's a reference given, but I don't have access to the article. The curl needs to be the desired magnetic field. Note that in both potentials the singularity in the denominator at the poles is canceled in the numerator at the pole that the respective potential is meant to cover but not at the other one. Note also that the potentials can be rewritten as $\tan\theta/2\,\hat e_\phi$ and $\tan(\pi-\theta)/2\,\hat e_\phi$, respectively.